# Auto comparing R-Code with a solution script

Tags: r, automated-tests, compare

How can I compare a R-Script automatically with a solution script when the objects are differently named and the script is longer than 2 lines.

Solution script:

```
table(bfi_i$age)
barplot(table(bfi_i$age),
        xlab = "Alter",
        ylab = "n")
x <- 3
```

Example script:

```
table(bfi_i$age) # correct
barplot(table(bfi_i$age)) # bracket too early
        xlab = "Altersgruppe" # missing comma
        ylab = "Haufigkeit" # missing comma
        col = c("lightblue", "mistyrose") # the place for the bracket
y <- 3 # correct
```

The package testwhat doesn't seem to help with more complex scripts. 
I would like it to keep it in RStudio because it has to be the natural kind of using R.

Can anybody help me with this?

My try so far. It is rather messy and without solution sheet yet:

```
# read all files
setwd('H:/')
folder_name <- getwd()
(all_files <- list.files(folder_name, include.dirs = F, recursive = F,
                        ignore.case = TRUE, pattern = glob2rx("*.R")))
student_files <- sapply(all_files, function(file) {
  student_code <- data.frame(Check = as.character(""),
                             read.delim(file, header = F, sep = "#",
                                        stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "`" 
                                        ))
  names(student_code)[2] <- "commands"
  names(student_code)[3] <- "comments"
  student_code
})

####check single files####
Erg1 <- student_files[[1]][1:3]
Erg1$Check<- as.character(Erg1$Check)
Erg1$commands <- trimws(Erg1$commands, which = c("both"))
test <- Erg1

setwd("H:/")
load("file.rda")

feedback <- c("correct", "1", "2")
x = 0; z = 0; cat('\14'); dev.off()
for(i in 1 : (nrow(test))) {
  cat(crayon::green(paste0(row.names(test[i, ]),". l: ", test[i, 3]), "\n"))
  if (test[i, 2] != "rm(list=ls())" && test[i, 2] != "cat('\\014')" && 
      test[i, 2] != "dev.off()" && !grepl("load", test[i, 2]) && 
      !grepl("setwd", test[i, 2])) {
    if (test[i, 2] != ""){
      # longer commands
      if (stringr::str_sub(test[i, 2], nchar(test[i, 2])) == ",") { 
        x = x + 1; next
      } else {
        cat("\n"); cat(crayon::underline(paste(test[(i - x) : i, 2], "\n")))
        test[(i - x), 1] <- sample(feedback, 1)
        tryCatch(print(z <- eval(parse(text = test[(i - x) : i, 2]))),
                 warning = function(w)  {
                   test[(i - x), 1] <- "Warning" # doesn't work yet
                   cat(crayon::red(crayon::bold("Warn_DF \n")))
                 },
                 error = function(e) {
                   test[(i - x), 1] <- "error" # doesn't work yet
                   cat(crayon::red(crayon::bold("error_DF \n")))
                 }
        )
        if (is.na(z) || is.character(z) || is.null(z)) {
          cat(crayon::red(crayon::bold("check_DF \n")))
        } else {cat(crayon::bold(paste(sample(feedback, 1), "\n")))}
        browser() # stop for each task
        x = 0}}}}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this in R? Syntax checking is something that really ought to be done as part of your IDE. Any solution you might find in R is going to be pretty clunky.

Comment: It's not an easy task. Different commands may result in the same output. Plus if the R code doesn't have valid syntax (things like missing commas make that so), the R parser isn't going to be able to scan it so you're basically going to have to re-create all the logic with basic string functions.

Comment: @bk18 As I teach statistics with R I didn't use another programs (IDE). Is there another way to correct syntax? However, I'm no programmer.

Comment: @MrFlick I would be happy to only correct wrong solutions. At the moment I have to check a lot of assignments.

Comment: @Daniela, by IDE I'm referring to the environment you write your R code in. Typically, these environments will include some syntax checking out of the box. If you're using notepad or something of the like, perhaps not. I personally use Emacs, but Rstudio offers a clean and easy-to-learn environment that will check your syntax as you go.

Comment: @bk18 I use RStudio. However, as I check in semester around 60 Script of students per week I look for an faster and more efficient way.

Comment: In that case, as @MrFlick pointed out; you're going to have to design some kind of hairy thing with basic string functions. It would consist of basically converting the script to a string and parsing it. It is almost certainly not worth the effort, though it would be cool if you did it!

Comment: How do you get the R scripts you want to check?

Comment: @JensDibbern Mostly, I download them from a website (moodle).

Comment: As @MrFlick stated before, this a difficult task to solve. You could start with https://github.com/jimhester/lintr to learn about static code analysis. Perhaps you could talk to someone in your university's computer science department. I would recommend the automated test approach to evaluate (a) if it runs and (b) if the output matches your reference result. I am afraid you have to redesign some of your exercises to do that.